# Git Repositories - Java with maven for Automation pipeline in azure - How can I add repository father for all the repositories?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, automation, testng

Using java with maven I have created the automation and it is managed in azure devops pipeline.
I would like to make 1 repository as the infra framework that contains the db connections, utils, helpers, report and dependencies and so on.
The purpose is to use all other repositories as minimum duplicate code and that they will get all the infra classes and dependencies from the infra repository.

How can I do that ? I have tried to convert the infra repo to jar file but it keeps telling me every time that class not found and things like that.

I appreciate the help here!

Comment: you could use a super pom or confihure it in the `~/.m2/settings.xml`.

Comment: Let me remind you that this repo is include classes, dependencies, settings.
how can I do that ?

Comment: So you want to import all dependencies etc of the repository?

Comment: not just importing, also it includes helpers and utils classes, Extent report classes and configs. Config properties files. testng.xml file, and all the infrastructure.
I want other repositories can fully used this one and will not have to do it over and over (dependencies, utils classes, xmls and so on)

Comment: Yes but do you want all dependencies located in one `maven repository` in all project?

Comment: I want that the main jar (main project infra repo) will contain all the dependencies and that the other projects can take from him what they need. I other word I want 1 project to role them all .

Comment: Just create the main project using `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. and include it with `<scope>import</import>` and `<type>pom</type>` or add it in the `<parent>` element.

Comment: Do you have any sample? Never tried it

Comment: I guess that the need is 
1. to work on same workspace with multiple projects / repositories.
2. To have 1 resource for all of them (dependencies, utils/helpers classes, xml and config files and so on).

Comment: util/helper classes and resources can just be put in a dependency.

Comment: but those classes are private, not published in maven central...
should work from pipeline

Comment: You can install a project to the local repository using `mvn install`.

Comment: That is not helpful because I need a flow to have all the repos getting the settings from super repo

Comment: yes, install the super/common repo to the local repository (or deploy it to some private repository) and use it as a dependency

Comment: How about add the project as jar and use it in other repos ?
when I tried it I got this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG

Comment: you need to either use a fat JAR/JAR with dependencies or include all dependencies of the project you create the JAR from in the project you use the JAR, too.

Comment: @dan1st
 I did it!
I build the project artifact then I used that Jar as library but I got:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
or:
Cannot instantiate class.
So I need some deep explanation or some sample code. please